# Registered fontawesome icons are not shown within the pagetree

Tags: icons, typo3, font-awesome, typo3-9.x

In ext_tables.php I register a fontawesome icon for a new pageDocType.

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconRegistry::class)
        ->registerIcon(
            'apps-pagetree-igstory',
            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconProvider\FontawesomeIconProvider::class,
            [
                'name'     => 'book',
                'spinning' => false
            ]
        );
```

The Icon is correctly shown in the drag-and-drop area above the page-tree.
But within the page-tree the icon isn't available.

[image]

If I use an SVG-Icon and integrate it with the SvgIconProvider, it works also in the page-tree.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like this is not supported by the page-tree in TYPO3 9

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/83468